# Why does piping out to /dev/null and grep, pollute my bash array?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I have two shell scripts (Linux , `#!/bin/bash`), one has some common functions in it for finding text etc., and the other making use of the common functions and doing some 'actual' work.

When examining an array variable (`oranges` inside `test2.sh`) to test/see if it's an array (`declare -p oranges 2>/dev/null | grep -q '^declare \-a' && printf "$fmt" "oranges is an indexed array"`), I stumbled across the fact that another array (`LINES` inside `test1.sh`) suddenly got "*polluted*" with a random number.

I cannot understand why this is happening. Anyone have an answer?
It makes zero difference if you echo or printf when working with the scripts, only if you pipe errors to 2>/dev/null AND grep the output. I've cut-down the scripts to the bare essentials to show the problem.
Also, the problem is easily worked around by breaking the one-liner apart and assigning the output from each piece to a variable(see `test3.sh`), so I'm not stuck on script writing or further progress. I am stuck on trying to answer why the pollution of `LINES` happens.

test1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a LINES

echo "::: DECLARE ::: Length of [LINES] is: ${#LINES[@]}, :::Content of [LINES] is: ${LINES[@]}"
```

test2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

source ./test1.sh

declare -a oranges=()
echo "::: test2-1 ::: Length of [LINES] is: ${#LINES[@]}, :::Content of [LINES] is: ${LINES[@]}"


declare -p oranges 2>/dev/null
echo "::: test2-2 ::: Length of [LINES] is: ${#LINES[@]}, :::Content of [LINES] is: ${LINES[@]}"


declare -p oranges 2>/dev/null | grep -E -i '^declare \-a'
echo "::: test2-3 ::: Length of [LINES] is: ${#LINES[@]}, :::Content of [LINES] is: ${LINES[@]}"


declare -p oranges 2>/dev/null | grep -E -i '^declare \-a' && printf "$fmt" "oranges is an indexed array"
echo "::: test2-4 ::: Length of [LINES] is: ${#LINES[@]}, :::Content of [LINES] is: ${LINES[@]}"

declare -p LINES
declare -p oranges 2>/dev/null | grep -E -i '^declare \-a' && printf "$fmt" "oranges is an indexed array" || printf "$fmt" "oranges is not an indexed array"
echo "::: test2-5 ::: Length of [LINES] is: ${#LINES[@]}, :::Content of [LINES] is: ${LINES[@]}"


declare -p oranges 2>/dev/null
echo "::: test2-6 ::: Length of [LINES] is: ${#LINES[@]}, :::Content of [LINES] is: ${LINES[@]}"
```

And when run, the following output occurs:

```
::: DECLARE ::: Length of [LINES] is: 0, :::Content of [LINES] is: 
::: test2-1 ::: Length of [LINES] is: 0, :::Content of [LINES] is: 
declare -a oranges=()
::: test2-2 ::: Length of [LINES] is: 0, :::Content of [LINES] is: 
declare -a oranges=()
::: test2-3 ::: Length of [LINES] is: 1, :::Content of [LINES] is: 81
declare -a oranges=()
::: test2-4 ::: Length of [LINES] is: 1, :::Content of [LINES] is: 81
declare -a LINES=([0]="81")
declare -a oranges=()
::: test2-5 ::: Length of [LINES] is: 1, :::Content of [LINES] is: 81
declare -a oranges=()
::: test2-6 ::: Length of [LINES] is: 1, :::Content of [LINES] is: 81
```

test3.sh - the workaround

```
#!/bin/bash

source ./test1.sh

declare -a oranges=()
echo "::: test2-1 ::: Length of [LINES] is: ${#LINES[@]}, :::Content of [LINES] is: ${LINES[@]}"


someResult="$(declare -p oranges 2>/dev/null)"
thePattern="^declare \-a"

nextResult=`grep -E -i "$thePattern" <<< "$someResult"` || nextResult=""

if [[ -n "$nextResult" ]]
then
    echo "oranges is an indexed array"
else
    echo "oranges is NOT an indexed array"
fi

echo "::: test2-2 ::: Length of [LINES] is: ${#LINES[@]}, :::Content of [LINES] is: ${LINES[@]}"
```

Output from test3.sh ..

```
$ ./test3.sh 
::: DECLARE ::: Length of [LINES] is: 0, :::Content of [LINES] is: 
::: test2-1 ::: Length of [LINES] is: 0, :::Content of [LINES] is: 
oranges is an indexed array
::: test2-2 ::: Length of [LINES] is: 0, :::Content of [LINES] is:
```

Comment: I notice that in your weird output (the "error" case), we never see the text _ oranges is an indexed array_, though this should be printed, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LINES` is a special variable populated by the shell with the number of rows that may fit in the terminal window. Use a different variable name (which isn't used by the shell, see [Shell Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Variables.html#Shell-Variables)) and it'll work.

As David C. Rankin mentions in his comment, variables in all upper-case are generally reserved for the shell, which is why use of lower-case variable names is recommended.

If you **have to** use the name LINES for your variable for some reason, you can try disabling the `checkwinsize` option by the following command as a workaround:

```
shopt -u checkwinsize
```

Comment: Worth a comment that variables in all UPPER-CASE are generally reserved for the shell, which is why use of lower-case variable names is recommended... May want to have him try `echo $LINES` and `echo $COLUMNS` from an xterm to see why the conflict exists `:)`

Comment: @David right. But an explanation as to why the shell populates LINES when a pipeline is executed would be even better, as the manual doesn't say anything about it. I guess bash retrieves the terminal configuration while setting the foreground process group, and updates LINES and COLUMNS after that.

Comment: Maybe your answer does not really explain the problem: While I also remember having worked in a project, where `LINES` and `COLUMNS` was set automatically by bash, and even adjusted when resizing the Window, my bash **currently** does not do it, although the terminal can provide the information, and `TERM` looks correctly. And in the OPs example, LINES was initially _unset_. And even if this is related to the mechanism you suspected, 81 would be an unusual high value for the number of lines (though not impossible). Maybe the OP could let us know how many lines approximately his terminal has.

Comment: @user1934428 it's not unset, but given array attribute (Try `foo=1; declare -a foo; echo ${foo[@]}`). I don't know much about bash's internals, but you can clearly see that it updates LINES and COLUMNS variables when the output is a TTY and a pipeline with more than one components is executed by comparing `bash -c 'LINES=; :; echo $LINES'` to `bash -c 'LINES=; : | :; echo $LINES'`. This is bash 5.0.11 btw.

Comment: Ah, right. Of course it is set, because it was declared as an empty array.  I can not reproduce your example, though, because my bash unfortunately does not set this variable; but since `stty` also doesn't output information about terminal size, this might be a different issue.

Comment: @oguzismail in man bash, both `LINES` and `COLUMNS` are under the explanatory paragraph `"The following variables are used by the shell. ..."` and in the case of `LINES` it is `"Automatically set if the checkwinsize option is enabled or in an interactive shell..."` I would have to dive further -- but used by the shell means it can be used at any time -- which is what I suspect is leading to the overwriting behavior in the question.

Comment: @user1934428 Likely. That's a weird setting you got there.

Comment: @oguzismail : Perhaps I will contact the implementor of the terminal application. However, `tput lines` does produce the correct number, so perhaps bash is using a different mechanism than `tput`.

Comment: @oguzismail : Found the problem, after noticing, that it works correctly in my zsh! In bash, `checkwinsize` was not enabled. I could also reproduce the case that the variable is updated only after I have used  a pipe, although the man page says that it should be updated after each command.

Comment: @user1934428 You may send an e-mail to bug-bash@gnu.org and ask for clarification. I don't think Chet Ramey will be willing to lengthen the manual with intricate details about bash's internals, but at least you would get a clear explanation from the maintainer and share it with us and future viewers here.

Comment: @oguzismail  nice! Many thanks! I got so caught up in testing different scenarios of "why" that I missed other factors like the Shell reserved variables. And cheers to everyone for taking the time to dig into the problem and come back with replies. I updated my array variable name and all is good.

Comment: @user1934428 apologies, I missed your question. I run a Retina 5K iMac with Debian as my dev environment, and large window sizes are the norm when you have hundreds of rows of output, and my terminal indeed is sitting at 81 Lines and 187 Columns.

Answer (score 2):

This may explain the behaviour :

> d.  Non-interactive shells now react to the setting of checkwinsize
>   and set
>       LINES and COLUMNS after a foreground job exits.

from http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/Bash_history/bash43.shtml